# Are there two centers in a circle?

Tags: geometry

I read in a book that the center of the outcircle(intersect with each vertex) of a triangle is the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and the circle that every point on it makes the angle $2C$ with $A$ and $B$.But it has two intersections But we have only one single out circle.So why do we have two centers?

[image]

Comment: "But it has two intersections": who, what, where ??? "why do we have two centers": which two ?

Comment: no chance of two centers what so ever

Comment: Can you provide a picture about your question? It is not clear what you are really asking.

Comment: @Seyed Picture aded

Comment: @YvesDaoust Picture aded.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: you missed a fragment of the original text. "is the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisector of AB and ... "

Comment: Yves is right: the proper claim is not only that the center of the circumcircle lies on the bisector of $AB$, but *also* that it lies on the bisectors of $BC$ and $CA$ as well. In short: your memory was good, but not perfect. The second part of your memory is a slightly muddle statement of the inscribed angle theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).

Answer (score 1):

First, could you present the construction of circle that **every** point on it makes the angle $2C$ with $A$ and $B$ ?

If we assume, that this circle have a radius $r>0$, then:

- If this circle has points on both sides of $AB$, then there is point $C'$ on this circle that $AC'B=0^{\circ}$  or $AC'B=180^{\circ}$ (two points, where the circle intersects with line $AB$). But for the triangle with right angle $ACB$ (then $AC'B=180^{\circ}$) the circle must lie fully on the line $AB$, so it must be a single point ($r=0$)
- On the other hand, if the circle lies fully on one side of $AB$, there exists a poinf $C''$ on it,  that $AC''$ and $BC''$ intersects with the circle in points $A'\neq C''$ and $B'\neq C''$. Then for every point D on arc $A'B'$ we have $\angle AC''B > \angle ADB$.

So this circle can not have a positive radius. Thus it must be a single point. Or some different type of curve.

Second, we know two things:

- if $O$ is the center of outer circle of triangle $ABC$, then the angle $\angle AOB$ is central angle related with inscribed angle $\angle ACB$, so $\angle AOB=2 \angle ACB$
- the centre of the outer circle lies exactly on the intersection of bisectors of each side. In particular it lies somewhere on bisector of side $AB$.

See, that the sentence *In particular it lies somewhere on bisector of side $AB$* doesn't mean that every point on this bisector is the centre of the outer circle. On the other words, there is only one way implication (not equivalence!):
$$O \text{ is the centre} \Rightarrow O \text{ lies on bisector}$$

I belive your 'theorem' was

> *If $O$ is the center, then it satisfies these two conditions*

instead of

> *$O$ is the center, if it satisfies these two conditions*

or even

> *$O$ is the center, if and only if it satisfies these two conditions*

Comment: For someone whose first language is apparently not English, you've done a beautiful job of explaining something that is tangled up with the subtleties of English usage. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct figure.

[image]

It is quite remarkable that if you move a vertex alongthe circle, the angle beteen the incident sides doesn't change (except if it passes another vertex).

Answer (score 0):

The centre of the outcircle does indeed lie on the perpendicular bisector of AB, and it makes an angle of $2C$ with $A$ and $B$ (i.e. $A\hat XB=2C$). But the points with the second property do not form a circle; they form a circular arc. If $C<90^{\circ}$ then only the part of your circle above the line $AB$ is relevant. The second point you've marked, which lies below $AB$, actually gives an angle of $A\hat XB=180^{\circ}+2C$, so it is not the centre. If $C>90^{\circ}$ then it is the part of the circle below $AB$ which matters.